# Deploy to office store only desktop plug-in

Tags: excel, outlook, ms-word, ms-office, office365

I have plug-in written on C# for desktop Outlook. Is it possible to deploy it to Office store? 
I've review this manual https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins, but did not find any useful info about plug-in for desktop Office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Office Store is only for web add-ins, not .NET or COM add-ins.  Microsoft doesn't have a store or central marketplace (there used to be Office Marketplace) for COM add-ins.  You'll have to use your own Ecommerce provider to sell and distribute your add-in.  I've used Shopify in the past to sell Outlook add-ins and it worked great, but there are plenty of other options out there for publishing software.

Comment: One additional suggestion is to create a "companion" Office Add-in that is standalone-useful on its own, but also can be a funnel for channeling people towards the larger/more-powerful .NET-based add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Office Store is for HTML/JS add-ins. COM add-ins can be listed in the Windows Store only.